# beamer: \only with columns makes things move down

Tags: beamer

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \only<1->{Why does this move? :-(}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \only<2->{
      \[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]
    }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why does the line of text move down from the first page to the second?

What is the proper way to avoid this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`\only` does not reserve any space when the overlay is not active. Use `\onslide` instead, it leaves its contents as whitespace when not active:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \onslide<1->{Why does this move? :-(}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \onslide<2->{
      \[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]
    }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that works! Is there a difference between \visible and \onslide?

Comment: `\onslide` can have an optional `*` or a `+`, so that it can act like `\visible` or `\uncover`. And the argument can also be missing, then all the follwoing text will be in the overlay or not

Answer (score 14):

Use `\visible` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \only<1->{Why does this move? :-(}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \visible<2->{
      \[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]\[\int\]
    }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Explanation

When using `\only` the content gets only displayed on the specified slide and uses no space for it. Whereas the usage of `\visible` always uses the space for the corresponding  element even if it's not shown. Using the `\visible` command avoids "jumping" slides.