# Avoid height flickering in a block when hiding content with \only

Tags: beamer

When using a construction like the following, the height of the block changes between frames. This change distracts the audience from the content. How to fix the height of the block, so that it doesn't "flicker"?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{MWE of flickering boxes}
\author{\textsc{Jon Doe}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Flickering boxheight}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{The upper box flickers}
  \begin{block}{\only<1-2>{Examples:} \only<3>{Pausetext:}\only<4>{Examples again:}}<1-4>
    \only<1-2,4>{\begin{itemize}
      \item<1-2,4> Example 1
      \item<2-,4> Example 2
    \end{itemize}}
    \only<3>{Oneliner}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Another Box}<3->
    Your Adverrtisement could be here
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ignasi - this could be regarded as a duplicate of the question you gave http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer, but this has an MWE and that does not; I also think it is better than the essentially similar http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44630/beamer-only-with-columns-makes-things-move-down, since it characterises why this is problematic and has the best answer.  I propose closing the other two as duplicates of this.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I agree with you. What should I do now? You can make suggestions in [What to do when a duplicate question and answer are better than the duplicate](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3468/1952)

Comment: @CharlesStewart Yes, I found [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer) but it didn't help me due to sparse information in answers, also I thought the question is of bad quality so I decided to ask it again in a "better" way and to provide a MWE. I am also curious about the new discussion Ignasi started in [What to do when a duplicate question and answer are better than the duplicate](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3468/1952)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (section **9.5 Dynamically Changing Text or Images**, p 84):

> You may sometimes wish to have some part of a frame change dynamically from slide to slide. On each slide of the frame, something different should be shown inside this area. You could achieve the effect of dynamically changing text by giving a list of `\only` commands like this:
>
> ```
> \only<1>{Initial text.}
> \only<2>{Replaced by this on second slide.}
> \only<3>{Replaced again by this on third slide.}
> ```
>
> The trouble with this approach is that it may lead to slight, but annoying differences in the heights of the lines, which may cause the whole frame to “wobble” from slide to slide. This problem becomes much more severe if the replacement text is several lines long.
>
> To solve this problem, you can use two environments: `overlayarea` and `overprint`. The first is more flexible, but less user-friendly

Here's an option using `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{MWE of flickering boxes}
\author{\textsc{Jon Doe}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Flickering boxheight}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The upper box flickers}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{5\baselineskip}
    \begin{block}{\only<1-2>{Examples:}\only<3>{Pausetext:}\only<4>{Examples again:}}<1-4>
      \only<1-2,4>{\begin{itemize}
        \item<1-2,4> Example 1
        \item<2-,4> Example 2
      \end{itemize}}
      \only<3>{Oneliner}
    \end{block}
  \end{overlayarea}
  \begin{block}{Another Box}<3->
    Your Adverrtisement could be here
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The overlay area was fixed to the entire `\linewidth` and has a height of `5\baselineskip`.